# Bet application, get odds of a winner team

Tags: php, mysql, algorithm, uml

I got 2 mysql tables:

> Match:
>    - id
>    - team1_id
>    - team2_id
>    - odds_team1
>    - odds_team2
>
> Bet:
>    - id
>    - date
>    - amount
>    - winner_prevision (team1_id or team2_id)

I need to display bet's potential benefit, depending on the winner_prevision.

> Formula : amount * (odds_team1 or odds_team2)

So i dont know how (mysql, php or both) can i get the correct odds_team after choosing the winner_prevision.

Maybe my tables composition is wrong, i'm listening on each suggestion !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really you should have 3 tables here

```
MATCH:
- match_id
- team1_id
- team2_id

ODDS

- match_id
- team_id
- odds

Bet:

- id
- match_id
- date
- amount
- winner_prevision (team1_id or team2_id)
```

Then your queries are easy (although this query is probably very wrong - you should use JOIN but I am trying to show the logic - if the actual query doesn't work then apologies!)

```
SELECT odds.odds AS odds, bet.amount AS amount, amount * odds AS `total` 
FROM odds, bet 
WHERE odds.team_id = Bet.winner_prevision 
AND MATCH.match_id = Bet.match_id
```

Hopefully the logic above makes sense - and the important part to note is the fact you can multiply within your mysql query `amount * odds`

Comment: Thanks for your fast response ! No problem for queries, i'll do that.
I'm thinking to your proposition, working on it. Thank you for this suggestion !

Comment: if this worked an accepted answer is always appreciated :-D - hope it does!